# Page children do not appear in wp_nav_menu

Tags: wordpress, menu

i am beginner in wordpress developement and try to write a theme.
At the moment I have these pages:

```
-Page 0
-Page 1
-Parent 1
---Child 1a
---Child 1b
-Parent 2
---Child 2a
---Child 2b
```

My purpose is to display a menu with Parent 1 and Parent 2 and their children.

```
                wp_nav_menu([
                    'theme_location' => 'unknown location',
                    'container' => false,
                    'menu_class' => 'nav__menu'
                ]);
```

display all the pages of first level and their children.
I have created a location and associate a menu with only Parent 1 and Parent 2

```
                wp_nav_menu([
                    'theme_location' => 'mylocation',
                    'container' => false,
                    'menu_class' => 'nav__menu'
                ]);
```

Displays parent 1 and parent 2 but not their children.
Is it possible to get these children automatically ?

Comment: It's very unclear what you are trying to do. `wp_nav_menu` should show the children by default. Where are you telling it what menu to use? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

Comment: Sorry for being not clear ! In my functions.php theme, I have : add_action('after_setup_theme',function(){
    register_nav_menu('header','Navigation');
}); In wp backoffice I have created a menu with the pages Parent 1 and Parent 2 and set its location to Navigation. Then I use wp_nav_menu([
                    'theme_location' => 'header',
                    'container' => false,
                    'menu_class' => 'nav__menu'
                ]); in header.php. It displays an ul with two li, one for Parent 1 one for Parent 2, but not their children.

Comment: Yes but where do you tell it which menu to use, i.e. the `menu` arg https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/ I don't know if that's what's wrong, but if you have more than one menu, I don't know how it's picking up the one you want

Comment: Hi ! My menuis titled 'Navigation', I have tried to ass 'menu'=>'Navigation' it's the same. For the moment, it is my first menu, the location 'header' the name 'Navigation'. My menu is well displayed with its two pages, and i am lloking for a way to add the children of the pages of the menu automatically. Thank you for your attention !

Comment: If it’s picking up the correct menu and that menu is set up properly, then something else in your then or plugins is affecting it - it could be custom nav walker code or even just css hiding child menus, but without being able to see your whole setup I’m afraid we can’t tell what it might be. Try narrowing it down by disabling plugins and trying one of the default WP themes, then when you find out which you’ll need to look into that code a bit more. That’s all we can really help with without any more info though. Good luck :)